# How do I forward TCP port 80 to web server (using nginx)?

Tags: tcp, nginx

I am following [this tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/3/) and I made the server work in the local network. Now I want to open to the internet. The tutorial does not go into details, except saying that "you need to forward TCP port 80 to your Web server". I did some research to understand what this means, but could not find a good step by step instructions. Can you direct me to any material that I can read to set up the server for the internet?

---

**EDIT**

As instructed [here](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/223583) I connected to the router with `192.168.1.1` and opened the Port Forwarding/Port Triggering tab and I entered the following information:

- Service Name HTTP
- Start Port: 80
- End Port: 80
- Server IP Address: ServerIPAddress

Is this correct?

Comment: Means that you have to forward http request from publicIP:80 to privateIP:80. This can be done with proxies, firewalls. Are we talking about a home network or a corporate network ?

Comment: @user2196728 this is a home network

Comment: So you certainly have a box which provides you Internet access. Login to your box and search for a feature like routing/port-forwarding config. Sorry, as i am french i cannot be more precise because i don't know which boxes types are available elsewhere in the world. But let's try : what is your box or how do you access to Internet ?

Comment: @user2196728 Thanks. I have cable for internet access. Is this what you mean? I am not sure how I log to the "box". Where is the box?

Comment: @user2196728 I connected to the router and I entered the port information. Can you look at the edits on my question if they are correct?

Comment: @user2196728 How can I test this? I went out and tried from an internet cafe but couldn't connect. But I tried it from my phone and I was able to connect. Does this mean it is working now?

Comment: It depends, do you have a home Wifi where your phone was connected to or were you connected to an operator network (3G) ? Send me (private if you prefer) your url, i will test it

Comment: @user2196728 You are right, I was connecting through home wifi. But I disconnect it and tried through 3G and it worked as well. How can I send you the url privately? Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43185/discussion-between-user2196728-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you have to forward http request coming to your public_ip:80 to your private_ip:80.

This is usually done with proxies or firewalls.

As we are talking about home network here, i think you have a home box/router that provides you internet access.

So you have to login to your box/router and searh for a feature like routing/port-forwarding configuration settings.
Then configure it to forward port 80 to your web server private ip on port 80.

Comment: If you are having a similar problem see also this answer for more information http://serverfault.com/questions/561488/how-can-i-open-port-80-with-netgear-wireless-router-wnr2000v3